# Redirect *.htm to *.php

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I am trying find out how to redirect all traffic on a website from any .htm address to a .php version of the page. I am hoping it will be a .htaccess rule but I have not been able to find anything that quite fits for me yet and I am not the greatest with .htaccess.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do the job in your .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.htm$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect **file.html** to **file.php** without causing an infinite looping error.