# Converting HTML to PHP while preserving SEO

Tags: php, html, seo

I created my web page and it has grown over time.  When I originally made the page, I didn't create the PHP function for my header and footer and since I didn't want to spend the time to fix it, I just left it.

I have finally got to the point where wanted to add the PHP Include function which worked perfectly except it seems that I have to change all my pages from .html to .php.

What will that do to all the SEO work I have done over time?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Search engines don't see server side code. They only see the HTML it produces. So using includes doesn't affect SEO.

In your case your URLs have changed, so you either need to do a [301 redirect from the old URLs to the new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610973/redirect-htm-to-php) or [make your site run PHP pages with a .html extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files/11312349#11312349).