# htaccess file still best way to redirect .htm to .php version of file?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I am ready to launch a new version of an existing site which currently has all .htm files and the new files will be exactly the same name but with a .php extension - is updating the htaccess file with:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.htm$ $1.php
```

still the best way to redirect all of these files?

I have never done this through the htaccess file, I have read the change is immediate.

I found this answer on this site but it was from 2012 so I just want to be sure it is still the best solution.

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+?)\.htm$ $1.php` should work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect \*.htm to \*.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610973/redirect-htm-to-php)

Comment: Great, thank you!  This may be obvious but I can then take down all of the .htm files right?

Comment: Thank you Juhana, I did see that ... I just noticed the date and wanted to be sure that was still the best way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+?)\.htm$ $1.php` into your .htaccess file should be fine if you're running Apache.

However, if you're using nginx for example, you cannot use .htaccess files.

(If you're using nginx, try taking a a read [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx).)